# flask 404 error under windows

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-404

I am trying to run a small flask modular application under windows 10. I have created a module to lunch the index page. While as a single application runs correctly and loads the home page, I cannot make it modular getting a 404 error page not found.

Here is my directory structure:

[Application directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVpxC.png)

My files:

**runserver.py**

```
import os
#from app.models import User, Role
from flask import Flask


basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

from landingpage import app

app = Flask(__name__)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**__init__.py**

```
   import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, session, redirect, url_for
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask.ext.moment import Moment
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, TextField, DateField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Required
from wtforms.fields.html5 import DateField
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.admin.form.widgets import DatePickerWidget





basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
#print "basedir is %r " % (basedir)
app = Flask(__name__)


import views

class AnotherSearchForm(Form):
    place = StringField(default=u'Où voulez-vous aller?', validators=[Required()])
    checkin =TextField(default=u'checkin', validators=[Required()])
    checkout=TextField(default=u'checkout', validators=[Required()])
    dt = DateField('DatePicker', format='%Y-%m-%d')

    submit = SubmitField('Rechercher')
```

**views.py**

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, redirect, url_for, current_app


#from .. import db
#from ..models import User
#from ..email import send_email
import landingpage
from landingpage import app
#from .forms import AnotherSearchForm




@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    form = AnotherSearchForm()
    return render_template('indexnew.html',
                           title='Home',
                           form=form)
```

The application is running correctly as you see below,

```
$ python runserver.py
C:\Users\admin\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:800: UserWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn('SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True to suppress this warning.')
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
```

but is failing to load the home page **indexnew.html** on  http://127.0.0.1:5000/ giving a 404 error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2016 14:10:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: Do you get any output on the command line when accessing the page?

Comment: only the error  404 above.

Comment: To me it looks like the views.py is not properly imported.

Comment: But all other imports like landing.views or . views  givining also a module not found error.

Comment: Test it, put a `print` line at the bottom and see if it prints to the console.

Comment: I tested  python __init__.py and got the error  File "C:\Users\admin\myApp\landingpage\views.py", line 9, in <module>

Comment: import landingpage
ImportError: No module named landingpage

Comment: it seems views is not imported

Comment: Then add a proper absolute import.

Comment: import myApp.landingpage.views
ImportError: No module named myApp.landingpage.views

Comment: I think it is correctly importing the views but views is failing at File "__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    import views
  File "C:\Users\admin\myApp\landingpage\views.py", line 10, in <module>
    from landingpage import app
ImportError: No module named landingpage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have app defined in `runserver.py` as well as in your `__init__.py`

I suspect that `runserver.py` is running the app defined there, while your real application is actually being set up and then overridden by your `runserver.py`.

You want to import `app` within `runserver.py` and use that, rather than define it again.

In other words, remove this line from `runserver.py`...

> `app = Flask(__name__)`

## update

I've got a version of your code that has the fix I suggest. You can find it on GitHub:

https://github.com/martinpeck/stackoverflow_example_1

I took your code. It failed in two ways:

1. your import of views didn't work for me
2. once I'd fixed that, I saw the 404

To fix your code:

1. replace `import views` with `import landingpage.views` in `__init__.py`
2. as suggested above, remove `app = Flask(__name__)` from `runserver.py`

Comment: @IPPOKRATISKARAKOTSOGLOU Feel free to mark my answer as correct if it has fixed your problem. It'll help me, and it'll help others find the answer to similar problems.

Comment: I am very sorry. I just did it now. Great job.